# Excel vba macro - process iframes

Tags: html, excel, vba, iframe

As long as I've seen the vollowing code should work:

```
Sub iFrameInnerHTML()
    Const cURL = "https://invest.ameritrade.com/grid/p/login?logout=L&promo=3"
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate cURL

    Do While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim iFrm As HTMLIFrame
    Set iFrm = IE.Document.frames(1).Document.getElementById("noscript-frame")
    Debug.Print iFrm.Document.body.innerText
End Sub
```

But I obain an error in "set iFrm = ...." line.

Any help would be appreciated.
Alvaro de Leon

Comment: You should make sure the framed document has completed loading: your code only checks the status of the parent page.

Comment: error '-2147562319)' at execution time. Error in method 'frames' object 'JScriptTypeInfo'

Comment: You're right, formally the program is not making sure that the framed doc has loaded completely. Anyway, (1) the error seems to be a syntax error, that I don`t understand and (2) in debugging mode, I waited long enough to be sure that the frame is loaded; got the same error.

Comment: This Sub is very simple and should work, just copied and pasted as an Excel macro.  Perhaps somebody can reproduce this behaviour and find out what is happening. Thank you.

Comment: The URL you posted has no `frame` or `iframe` elements, except within a `<noscript>` block.  Unless scripting is turned off, that block doesn't render, and so is not part of the HTML DOM. So you can't reference it using `getElementById()`

Comment: @TimWilliams - I am working with https://navinet.navimedix.com/sign-in and it has got frames but I'm getting the error : Error in method 'frames' object 'JScriptTypeInfo'. Any help?

Comment: @student - if you need help you should ask a question (with more details, and code)